# Pentaho Data Integration - Snowflake - Convert field to Data Type VARIANT

Tags: json, pentaho, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, kettle

I have just started the study about Snowflake and I faced with one situation:

I'm creating a JOB in pentaho data integration, to conect in this URL to get the JSON:
https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json

To load it into a snowflake table, I must have a Data Type as a VARIANT. My column is already variant, but when I create the JOB, Pentaho is not able to convert the streaming  to a VARIANT Data Type and them I got the error that I cannot insert VARCHAR value into VARIANT data type.

Is there any workaround for that?

Thank you very much.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djHbS.png)

Comment: what is the exact error. ? you can load the data into stage. and then string into variant.

Comment: Hi @Vinícius Zamuner have you already seen this resource: https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/video/snowflake-bulk-loading.html Pay attention to the options tab in the tutorial. We would need a copy of the error to understand how it works, but I also have not seen a git file path uploaded to Snowflake before. Is it mapped to a local file path to put onto Snowflake Stage?

Comment: Follow the error here https://i.stack.imgur.com/djHbS.png   The point is. Im tring to send a JSON, that I got from streaming to a table that has a column as a VARIANT type. And this Streaming has a VARCHAR as a value. I should convert this streaming, that is a JSON to a VARIANT type, to make it work. right?